# Software to create an app from existing algorithm in limited time

Tags: android, iphone-app

**App Idea:** The app will be connected to a surveillance camera and will detect the presence of a dog in real-time. The user should be able to turn the detection system on or off. Immediately, if a dog is detected (and the detection system is on), the app should ring an alarm and display some kind of message on the screen. As soon as this happens, the phone should detect nearby phones (with the app installed) using Bluetooth (perhaps using iBeacon) and display the registered names of each user (in the app) for each of the detected phones. The user should also be able to choose which users they want their names to be displayed to and for which users the names should be anonymous.

**Question:** I have already created an algorithm in Python in Google Collab which detects the presence of a dog in real-time footage. I want to use this algorithm and some app development software to create the app described above. I have no app development experience and roughly about 1 week to create this app. What app development software would be best to implement the above given my circumstances?

**Note:** I have no specific preference for ios or android - my choice is solely dependant on which is more convenient.

Comment: To create a program you absolutely need to know programming and lots of details. No software will program an app for you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be slightly out of scope for this stack site, but my advise is to make web wrapper type of app. You can use ionic or react native.

With ionic, you more or less make a website with HTML,JS and CSS, which is then bundled in a webview/browser wrapper that appears as an app (supports both android and ios) to the user. Although 1 week is quite short to grasp building mobile applications.

Comment: Agreed, this is not a 1 week task for an experienced developer.

Comment: Thanks! In Ionic, would I need to rewrite my Python code in JavaScript or is there some other way?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if you can somehow build a light client that streams to a server for the video feed. Also, you might check if there is a way to convert python TensorFlow to TensorFlow  JS which is what I assume you are using